# Base path for Zend ViewScript decorator

Tags: zend-framework

I need to change the rendering of an element in my Zend_Form. I like the idea of the Zend_Form_Decorator_ViewScript but I'm not using Zend's MVC and can not (after three hours of searching) find how to **set the path to the base directory of the viewScript**. I have tried every option I could find but nothing works. I get this message:

> 'no view script directory set; unable
>   to determine location for view script'

If anyone can point me in the right direction or fill in the blanks for this piece of code **you would make my day!**

```
  $this->addElement(
     "text",
     "customer_name",
     array(
        "label"=>"Your name",
        "required"=>false,
        "decorators"=>array(
           "PrepareElements",
           array(
              "ViewScript",
              array(
                 "viewScript"=>"customer_name.html"
              )
           )
        )
     )
  );
```

Please again note that I am not using Zend's MVC so I need to set the path explicitly.

Comment: http://www.tibobeijen.nl/blog/2009/12/07/using-zend_form-without-zend-framework-mvc/

Comment: Thanks for the link, it has some good information on how to use Zend_Form without MVC. Unfortunately it doesn't answer my particular problem (from what I can see), which is how to fix the path to the viewScript if one's not using MVC. I will continue reading though, so thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Iam note sure, it is along time ago since i have used Zend Framework without MVC Structure, but this should work (based on the Example link in the comments)

```
$view = new Zend_View();
$view->doctype('XHTML1_TRANSITIONAL');
$view->setBasePath('/path/to/your/view');

$form = new Zend_Form();
$form->setView($view);
```

Comment: Thank you! Almost... This works:

$form = new Zend_Form();
$view = new Zend_View();

$view->setScriptPath('/path/to/your/view');
$form->setView($view);

Comment: setBasePath is the same as setScriptPath